# I want to print the letters in each word in matrix form given the number of columns

Tags: python, string, matrix

I have a string `thestackoverflow`
and I also have # columns = 4
Then I want the output as

```
thes  
tack  
over  
flow
```

Comment: don't add tag `design-patterns` see the tag description before you adding it to your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using python slice notation.
refer to this thread for a nice explanation on slice notation: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

example code for your question:

```
>>> input_string = "thestackoverflow"
>>> chop_size = 4
>>> while(input_string):
...  print input_string[:chop_size]
...  input_string = input_string[chop_size:]
...
thes
tack
over
flow
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at `textwrap`

```
import textwrap
string = 'thestackoverflow'
max_width = 4
result = textwrap.fill(string,max_width)
print(result)
```

```
thes
tack
over
flow
```

If you don't want to use any module

```
string = 'thestackoverflow'
max_width = 4
row = 0
result = ''
while row*max_width < len(string):
    result+='\n'+string[row*max_width:(row+1)*max_width]
    row+=1
result = result.strip()
print(result)
```